# Gzip compression for files outside the template

Tags: joomla-3.x, compression

In global configuration I have **buffering set to conservative**, **compression enabled** and in JCH Optimize settings set like this (Tak means yes in Polish :)

[image: JCH Optimize]

On http://checkgzipcompression.com/ they say:

**YES, it's GZIP enabled!**

Uncompressed size:85,908 bytes Compressed size:17,648 bytes
By compressing this page with GZIP, 79.5% bandwidth was saved.

But, when I open PageSpeed ​​Insights for Chrome, it tells me to **turn on** the compression to reduce transfer by 185.1 KB (74%). It also lists the files that are not compressed (css and js) - and all of them are inside '**plugins**' or '**modules**' directories (for example /plugins/system/jcemediabox/js/jcemediabox.js?f164ea24e8567d41a795089153b69cd9 - from JCE plugin)

So the question is, how to tell Joomla to compress not only files from the template but also from other directories?

Joomla 3.35, JCH 4.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the source html in the browser for your homepage. 
If you see a line like this

```
 /plugins/system/jch_optimize/assets/nz/1/0/486f81270d21c22c4aee77df7e.js
```

this is a file JCH has compressed but if you also see other .js files that are not like this then some extensions or templates are not using the normal joomla code and so are not being compressed.
You can look through these and see if it is possible to change them or not.

At the end of the day this all makes you pages smaller and faster but does not effect what the users can do, so at a certain point you have to move on and do content and sales tasks.

Comment: There are a many lines like you mentioned, but also many links to uncompressed css and js files just like before the JCH activation. 
I checked them and it appears all of them are loaded via my custom modules or a jcemediabox plugin.
I've checked my modules' code and all script and css references are made like this:
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet( JURI::root(true) . '/modules/mod_mymodule/css/style.css' );
$doc->addScript(JURI::root(true) . '/modules/mod_mymodule/js/script.js', 'text/javascript');

Answer (score 1):

JCH will by default compress all Javascript/CSS files whether they belong to your template or not, unless you exclude them manually, which I assume you haven't done.

Personally I would not go by what a browser extension says. I recommend you test with a popular online service such as [GTmatrix](http://gtmetrix.com). This will give you all the accurate information you need, including GZip.

Comment: I've analized the page with http://gtmetrix.com/ and it gives me same results as PageSpeed ​​Insights listing files to compress and minify - which, to my understanding, are all the css and js files that are loaded by modules and plugins. The files loaded by the template itself seem to be compressed and minified correctly.